# I get an error while simply trying to download the R package "treemap"

Tags: r

The code I use to install treemap:

```
install.packages("treemap", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies=TRUE)`
```

The error message in the console:

```
    `gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c AMD/Source/amd.f -o AMD/Source/amd.ostrong text
make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
make: *** [AMD/Source/amd.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘igraph’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/igraph’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/nw/1cr0b8lj79schd118jjplx4w0000gn/T/RtmpN44Udu/downloaded_packages’
Error in -install.packages("treemap", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/",  : 
  invalid argument to unary operator
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Mac OS Catalina 10.15.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you added an extra character before the function call. Notice the error message has a `-` right before `install.packages()`. So the install actually runs fine, then the return value gets passed to the `-` operator which needs another argument, hence the strange error message.

Comment: The OP saw "Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘igraph’ * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/igraph’ " so most likely the igraph failed to install

Comment: try -install.packages("treemap") and you will not see those error messages about igraph

Comment: thank you guys for the answers, I ended up simply typing "N" or no when I was asked the prompt "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compliation?"